# Predicate Logic, confusion about implication statement.

Tags: logic

Let's say the domain of discourse is the set of 10 balls, numbered as such from 1 to 10. Some (more than 1 but NOT all) of those balls are put into a bag, and then some of those in the first bag are transferred to a second bag.

P(x) means that x is was the first bag, Q(x) means that x is in the second bag.

The statement says: $$\forall x. (P(x) \rightarrow Q(5))$$  where 5 stands for ball #5, uniquely identifiable as such.

Basically I'm not sure whether this should be taken as saying "if **every** ball was in the first bag, then ball #5 is in the second bag" (in which case ball #5 is not in the second bag), or "if **any** ball was in the first bag, then ball #5 is in the second bag" (in which case it is).

I would tend toward the latter, but I'm having a really hard time making sense out of it.

Comment: I would translate it as "Forall balls that are in the first bag, ball #5 is in the second".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that there is a typo; you write :

> "$P(x)$ means that $x$ **is was** the first bag, $Q(x)$ means that $x$ is in the second bag"

but I think it must be :

> "$P(x)$ means that $x$ **was in** the first bag, ...

Assuming this reading, your formula :

> $\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow Q(5))$

must be read - along the line suggested by @frabala - as :

> "for all balls $x$, if $x$ is in the first bag, then ball #5 is in the second".

It is different from :

> $\forall x P(x) \rightarrow Q(5)$

that must be read as :

> > "if all balls were in the first bag, then ball #5 is in the second".

But you said that not all the balls were in the first bag, so I presume that the first formula is what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively, $\forall x (P(x)\to Q(5))$ is the same as $\forall x\in P, Q(5)$.

*For all balls (if the ball is in first bag, then ball #5 is in the second)*, which is the same as *for all balls in first bag, ball #5 is in the second*.

Such a logical sentence doesn't really make sense to me, since $x$ does not appear at the conclusion of the implication, but I wouldn't know the context of the exercise.

Comment: @user18921 Yes, I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Since your universe is finite, you have the luxury of being able to simply unfold the quantifier if you're unsure of what it means. $\forall x(P(x)\to Q(5))$ means neither more nor less than
$$ (P(1)\to Q(5))\land(P(2)\to Q(5))\land \cdots \land (P(9)\to Q(5)) \land (P(10)\to Q(5))$$

A bit of thought ought to convince you that the condition for this to be true is that if there is *anything* that $P$ holds for, then $Q(5)$ must hold too.

This is the same as saying $(\exists x P(x))\to Q(5)$, and it is probably more common to write it in that form. But there's nothing disallowed about writing $\forall x(P(x)\to Q(5))$. In fact, there are several situations in formal logic where it is technically convenient to be able to write a formula such that all of the quantifiers are at the front, and none are hidden inside the logicial structure. One of the rules that allow that is exactly that $(\exists x.\varphi)\to\psi$ is equivalent to $\forall x(\varphi\to\psi)$ (when the formula $\psi$ doesn't depend on $x$).

Comment: excuse me ... but I'm not sure to understand (disclaim : I'm not an English speaker : so my "perception" of *anything* must be wrong). When you say that : "the condition for this to be true is that if there is anything that $P$ holds for, then $Q(5)$ must hold too" are you saying that for the conjunction being true is suffient that $P(x)$ holds for $1$ or $2$ or $3$ or $4$ or $5$ ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: No -- what the entire conjunction says is "IF (there is _anything_ that P is true for) THEN Q(5) is true".

Comment: @Henning. Since the whole unfolded expression is an AND'ing of terms (implications in this case), doesn't each term need to evaluate to True in order for the entire expression to be True? So, if one implication (let's say P(6) --> Q(5) is False, doesn't the whole thing evaluate to False?

Comment: @jeremyradcliff - I've made the same mistake. We are not searching for a tautology, but only for "equivalence of meaning". The case you are alluding to is when $Q(5)$ is false and "one of" $P$s is true, for example $P(1) \land Q(5)$. In this case the conjunctions evaluates to false. But also $\exists x P(x) \rightarrow Q(5)$ will be fasle, due to the fact that the antecedent is true and $Q(5)$ is false.

Comment: @jeremy: Yes, if $P(6)\to Q(5)$ is false, then the entire thing is false. But the only way for $P(6)\to Q(5)$ to be false is that $P(6)$ is true and $Q(5)$ is false. So since $P(6)$ it is true that there is _something_ $P$ is true for, so the implication $(\exists x.P(x))\to Q(x)$ is _also_ false then.

Comment: @jeremyradcliff - the argument is a little bit tricky: so you can use truth-tables. *(i)* forget about $Q(5)$ and consider only $Q$ (the only relevant fact is that $x$ must not be free in it). *(ii)* simplify further, considering only $P(1)$ and $P(2)$. *(iii)* when $Q$ is *true*, all "combinations" give us *true*, because "if ..., then *true*" evaluates to *true* wahtever you put in front; so $\exists x P(x) \rightarrow Q$ and $\forall x P(x) \rightarrow Q$ and $(P(1) \rightarrow Q) \land (P(2) \rightarrow Q)$ are all *true*. 1/2

Comment: Now we have a 4-rows truth-table (with $Q$ *false*): it is easy to check it. In the case with $P(1)=P(2)=false$, all three formulas evaluate to *true*, while in the three other cases, all evaluate to *false*. So, we have checked that : $\forall x P(x) \rightarrow Q$, $\exists x P(x) \rightarrow Q$ and $(P(1) \rightarrow Q) \land ... \land (P(n) \rightarrow Q)$ are all *equivalent*. 2/2

Comment: Thanks a lot Mauro and Henning, it makes sense now.